# Prevent multiple calls of onPress

Tags: react-native

I have a bottom that adds an item through redux action.

```js
    onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
        store.dispatch(add(construct(name)))
    }}
```

Sometimes onPress is being called more than once on a single tap and it adds more than one item. I want to prevent that. 
Of course I can make a boolean and check if it's true, but it's not very elegant way. Is there a better way to prevent it?

Comment: `construct` is an async action ?

Comment: no, it's synchronous, but very simple. It's making an object with few variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way as you said is to define a boolean flag, but another way to solve your problem is by using redux-saga. I know redux-saga is designed to solve async actions but it can help you here too.
check the `takeLatest` from [here](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/). by this helper, if you click more than one time, it will run the latest one only.